# Protobuf: Will set_allocated_* delete the allocated object?

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I have this small protobuf code (simplified, only the necessary is contained):

```
message ParamsMessage {
    required int32 temperature = 1;
}

message MasterMessage {
    enum Type { GETPARAMS = 1; SENDPARAMS = 2;}
    required Type type = 1;

    optional ParamsMessage paramsMessage = 2;

}
```

I now create a MasterMessage in the following way:

```
ParamsMessage * params = new ParamsMessage();
params->set_temperature(22);
MasterMessage master;
master.set_type(MasterMessage::SENDPARAMS);
master.set_allocated_paramsmessage(params);
```

The question is: Do I have to (after dealing with the message) delete the `params` Message, or will protobuf delete it for me? I cannot find anything in the docs.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Since asking the question I have continued searching for the answer. Maybe someone else is interested in the answer too.

From here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp-generated

> void set_allocated_foo(string* value): Sets the string object to the
> field and frees the previous field value if it exists. If the string
> pointer is not NULL, the message takes ownership of the allocated
> string object and has_foo() will return true. Otherwise, if the value
> is NULL, the behavior is the same as calling clear_foo(). string*
>
> release_foo(): Releases the ownership of the field and returns the
> pointer of the string object. After calling this, caller takes the
> ownership of the allocated string object, has_foo() will return false,
> and foo() will return the default value.

Which means: As long as you do **not** call `release_*`, protobuf will take care of deleting the object. If you need the Object after dealing with the Protobuf Message, you need to relase it using `release_*`, which will prevent Protobuf from deleting your object.

Comment: if I call myMessage.set_allocated_submessage(&submessage), I always have a Segmentation Fault at the end (Destruction of object ? ). It solves only if I manually myMessage.release_submessage(). I don't understand why I have a segmentation if I don't use my subMessage... Do you think my problem needs a independant post ?

Comment: yes, you should post it as an independent question.

Comment: @Maxime.D - long dead question, but it's probably because of double free.  As the post says protobuf will delete it for you.  Don't leave submessage on the stack.

Comment: @Alex thanks but I had my answer after I posted a question