# Clang Static Analyzer complains about memory leak when using protobuf's set_allocated_*

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, clang-static-analyzer, clang-tidy

With the following proto file

```proto
message Foo {
    // ...
}

message MyMessage {
    Foo foo = 1;
}
```

I set `foo` with the generated `set_allocated_foo` method which takes ownership of the pointer:

```cpp
MyMessage m;
m.set_allocated_foo(new Foo);
```

clang-tidy gives me the following warning though when `m` leaves the scope:

```
warning: Potential memory leak [clang-analyzer-cplusplus.NewDeleteLeaks]
}
^
note: Memory is allocated
    m.set_allocated_foo(new Foo);
                        ^
```

Is there any way to avoid that? (without using `// NOLINT`)

Comment: The answer is in following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33995232/994042. "As long as you do not call release_*, protobuf will take care of deleting the object. If you need the Object after dealing with the Protobuf Message, you need to relase it using release_*, which will prevent Protobuf to delete your object."

Comment: That just tells me that the warning is a false-positive. How do I avoid it?

Comment: You can disable check with: clang-tidy test.cpp -checks=-clang-analyzer-cplusplus.NewDeleteLeaks

Comment: That's even worse than using `// NOLINT`, because it will also disable other useful messages. So this is just a bug in clang-tidy?

Comment: "POTENTIAL memory leak" mean in this place the memory MAY not be freed. You can manual free it by yourself. It's not a bug of clang-tidy,  it may be a bug of a check of clang-tidy.

Comment: The memory will always be freed by the protobuf object and will never leak.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can do is using `#ifdef __clang_analyzer__`:

```
MyMessage m;
auto* f = new Foo;
m.set_allocated_foo(f);
#ifdef __clang_analyzer__
delete f
#endif
```

I don't know if it's the best way.